# What is the difference between pageX/Y clientX/Y screenX/Y in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

An example with some visual cue would be really helpful.

Comment: It is matter of confusion for most. Good question.

Answer (score 131):

## The visual cues represents:

[image: yellow] **Screen** → the full screen of the monitor (`screenX/Y`)
*Position will always be relative to the physical screen's viewport.*

[image: Blue] **Client** → the client viewport of the browser (`clientX/Y`)
*If you click in the left top corner the value will always be (0,0) independent on scroll position.*

[image: Red] **Document** → the complete document/page (`pageX/Y`)
*Note that `pageX`/`pageY` on the `UIEvent` object [are not standardized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX).*

All values are in pixels.

[image: screen snapshot with extended page illustration]

Comment: Oh I love the way you answer

Comment: This is an excellent answer!

Comment: Damn easy! Thank you)

Comment: Waah, too much recursion.

Answer (score 54):

[image]

### CLIENT → *The Browser window*

`clientX` `clientY` = values (`px`) of the mouse position relative to the Browser's viewport boundaries.
<sub>**Tip:**

Even if you scroll the Document, the values are always the same</sub>

---

### PAGE → *The Whole Document*

`pageX` `pageY` = values (`px`) of the mouse position relative to the Document most-top/left "sides".
<sub>**Tip:**

If you scroll the Document (i.e) vertically, `pageY` value changes cause it's the new mouse Top Position inside your Document.

Also it's worth noting that:

`event.pageY - event.clientY === document.documentElement.scrollTop` ( or jQuery's `$("html, body").scrollTop()` )</sub>

---

### SCREEN → *Your Screen*

`screenX` and `screenY` are the values (`px`) of the current mouse position relative to the **physical screen**.

### Mouse coordinates example:

```js
const EL = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);
EL("body").addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  ["client","page","screen"].forEach(mod => {
    EL(`#${mod}-x`).textContent = evt[mod+"X"];
    EL(`#${mod}-y`).textContent = evt[mod+"Y"];
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body{
  height: 300vh; /* just to force some scrollbars */
  font: 14px/1.5 monospace;
}
table{
  position:fixed;
  border-spacing:0; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td{
  vertical-align:bottom;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:3px 10px;
}
table tr:first-child{
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Mouse position inside:</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>screen</b> display</td><td id="screen-x"></td><td id="screen-y"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>client</b> viewport</td><td id="client-x"></td><td id="client-y"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>page</b> document (scroll to see diff))</td><td id="page-x"></td><td id="page-y"></td></tr>
</table>
```

- Additional read for [Mouse XY coordinates depending on parent / child positions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70691308/383904)

Answer (score 7):

Generally, the differences are:

- page x/y: the x or y coordinate as relative the to the fully rendered page (i.e., it considers the entire height and width of the page/document, not just what is currently being shown on screen)
- screen x/y: the x or y coordinate as relative to the physical screen.
- client x/y: the x or y coordinate as relative to the client (browser) window (or iframe inside the window.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_clientxy) is a page where you can test the differences dynamically.

Comment: Be careful with zoom settings of the browser. If it is greater than 100%, the difference (e.screenX - e.clientX) becomes not a constant, it increases when moving the mouse to the right edge of your client region.

Comment: Link broken just FYI