# Canvas FireFox X Y Coordinates

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

How to resolve X Y coords for any canvas in Firefox. I'm using clientX vs layerX in Firefox. For some reason layerX is not working.

```
   $("#circle").click(function(e) {

        painter.brush = function(e) {
            var shape = Circle(e.clientX, e.clientY, 0, paper);
            shapes.push(shape);

            $paper.bind('mousemove', function(e) {
                shape.updateEnd(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            });
        };

        $paper.bind('mouseup', function(e) {
            var shape = shapes.pop();             
            $(this).unbind('mousemove');
        });

        $paper.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
            painter.brush.call(this, e);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla notes this about `layerX`/`layerY` on their [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent.layerX?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.layerX):

> **Non-standard**
>  This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

In other words, try to stay clear of using these properties - it will just make problems for you as they won't work for everyone.

The more appropriate approach today is to use `getBoundingClientRect()` which is relative to the *client* window, aka viewport as the name suggest (speaking of which, document, page, client can be confusing, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262741/what-is-the-difference-between-pagex-y-clientx-y-screenx-y-in-javascript/17705548#17705548) to get an overview).

It will take scrolling into account ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect#Returns)):

> The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area (or
>   any other scrollable element) is taken into account when computing the
>   bounding rectangle.

But in order to compensate for the difference between the element's position and the mouse position we simply subtract the element's position from the mouse coordinates:

```
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
```

Now you will have correct position relative to canvas. There are a couple of caveats though:

- border thickness is not accounted for
- padding is not accounted for

There are a simple trick you can use if you need border and/or padding, and that is to insert the canvas element inside a div. Apply padding/border on the div element instead.

Or you can calculate the border/padding thickness using [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.getComputedStyle) for the element (left and top only), and then subtract those from the position as well.

Answer (score 1):

`e.clientX, e.clientY` reports coordinates relative to the <strike>document</strike> client window, not relative to the canvas.

Therefore you must account for the canvas's position on the document. You can use `.getBoundingClientRect` to get the position of the canvas relative to the document.

```
function handleMouseMove(e){
    BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-BB.left);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-BB.top);
}
```