# How to go to another page if fancybox right clicked?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, right-click

Friends,
I have an image gallery and it is functioning with fancybox plugin. This works perfectly on normal click.If I right click and open the link in a new tab,then the image is displaying in new tab.

```
<a href="<?php echo $data['path'];?>" class="fancybox" rel="road">View Image</a>
```

What I want to do is,

- If the user clicks right mouse button and open in a new tab then i want to display the image on a page that i have designed.

Is this possible? or how can i fulfill my goal.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your page is accessible you could just change the anchors `href` attribute and why not make it open in a new tab/window automatically with a `target` attribute?

```
<a href="<?php echo $mypage;?>" target="_blank" class="fancybox" rel="road">View Image</a>
```

If you want to do this with javascript, see documentation on the "contextmenu" event (right-click)

[How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)

Comment: Actually the problem is I got plenty of feed-backs that some of the user won't click my gallery and they just right click and open the links in new tabs.So they only see the clicked image on new tabs.What i tried to do is if they right clicks then a new page opens and show the image and some related images also

Comment: That's why I suggest you create pages (accessible via unique urls like "/images?id=12" for example) for your images. This way you just have to replace the 'href' of each anchor (a tag) so the your users will see those pages when they use your gallery as they do now.