# Add a copyright item to the browser right click menu

Tags: javascript, menu, right-click

I am just trying to add a copyright label to the default browser right click menu.
How could I accomplish this?

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage The accepted answer explains how to use the `contextmenu` event.

Comment: Don't. You are breaking usability. Someone wishing to "steal" your images can still do so, you're just making your site difficult to use for legit users.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is not possible. you have to handle right click event and show your custom [context](http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/right-click-context-menu-plugins/) menu.