# disable Delete menu item in context menu for input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, contextmenu

How do you disable/remove the delete menu item in a context-menu when you right-click on a HTML input box?

I'm interested in any possibilities to do this for particular control with Jquery/Javascript.

Comment: No, but you can replace the menu entirely.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't through JQuery/Javascript, but you can disable the **whole context menu** through Javascript:

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeX4h/)

See [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage):

By [singles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287464/singles):
Add a `contextmenu` event:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
```

and even though you can't disable the delete context menu item, you *can* through CSS by telling the user to add:

```
#context-delete
{
    display:none;
}
```

to `userChrome.css` if they're using Chrome; see http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=30260

It is, however, unfortunate, that you cannot disable menu items individually.