# Div with "onclick" function to have in browser same options like <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I make my `<div>` tag with `onclick()` function to have in browser same options like `<a>` tag ?

I need some options like "open in new window", "copy link location" ...

Comment: How would that even work - copy link location of what? Open the div in a New Window.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but in HTML5 you can wrap links around block-level elements.

```
<a href="#">
    <div>Hello!</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the div to act like a link, you should be using a link. Set the display to block and you got a block element.

The HTML:

```
<a class="I_AM_A_BLOCK" href="funky_chicken_dance.html">My Content</a>
```

The CSS:

```
.I_AM_A_BLOCK {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can create [a custom context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage), but most options on a link a not replicable in JavaScript (and you have no way of knowing what non-standard options extensions might have added).

You should probably be using a real `<a>` instead of trying to make a `<div>` behave like one.