# I want to deal with a particular cell in a listview using mouse right-clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview and I'd like it so that when the user right-clicks on one of the cells(I mean by the cell: the intersection field between certain column with a certain row), it would bring up a contextmenustrip with a few options or tasks the user could perform on that particular cell.
So my question is how to refer to that particular cell when right-clicks.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to google "javascript right click menu".

Or you could look at [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)