# Create a menu and action on right click on a textbox

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, right-click

I want to create a menu for right click on a text box and upon clicking on that option I should be able to call a js function. How should I do it? Can anybody please help me? My code for the text box is:

```
<g:textField size="40" name="txtBoxId" id="txtBoxId" title="" value="${session.circuitName}" readonly="true"/>
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Can you update your code, which you have tried.

Comment: my code for text box is ...Where is code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9v0vgLey/1/)**

**html:**

```
<input id="textbox"/>
```

**js:**

```
 $("#textbox").on('contextmenu', function (e) {
        alert("right-click!");
        window.event.returnValue = false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="id" type="text" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("id");
inputBox.addEventListener("contextmenu", handler, useCapture); // useCapture: true or false

//inputBox.attachEvent("oncontextmenu", handler); // IE <9; use attachEvent for IE <9 support.


function handler(event) {
    // your code goes here
    alert("right click on inputbox")
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnvalue = false; // IE <=9;
}
```

Here is my example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/70gjxsb7/1/)