# Disable right click WITHOUT an alert-box (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, alert, right-click

I want my website to not be right-clickable. I have tried finding out how and I found out. But I don't know how to disable it without an alert-box. I want nothing to happen when someone right clicks. I tried removing the alert from the code, but that didn't work.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
}
```

Answer based on [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage/4909312#4909312)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) this would be the way to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});
```

This should work.

Comment: I've submitted an edit telling the poster they need jQuery for this answer. As is, this solution would spout a bunch of errors.