# How can i create a new folder using right click?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working a project similar to google drive. I want to create a new folder using right click and folders inside a folder. How can I achieve this? I'm looking for the solution from past 3 days, didn't find any results for what I'm looking for. Any leads ?

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu

Comment: use `event.preventDefault();` and then call your function that let's you create a new folder. That's a bit too broad and you should attempt to do something yourself. But here is an example of calling functions with the right-click: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/TZQnS/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)