# How to capture HTML 5 Video element download event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

How to capture HTML 5 Video/ Audio element download event

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no shared event that fires for this action in the native context menu, at least not as defined in the media element spec. Your best option would be to [build your own context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage), add a download link to it (including the `download` attribute, and add a click listener to that link.

Comment: Thanks for your response