# Is there a way to add the "paste" option in any element when right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vuejs2

I want to enable the paste option of the context menu (right click menu) when someone right clicks in a div. It seems that it only appears in inputs and textareas, but the "paste" event is global.
I need people to right click a div and have the paste option in their menus.

Can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Short answer - Yes; however this is not a free code service. Please provide examples of what you have tried, what happened vs expected, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is no longer supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contextmenu

But, you can build your own contextmenu. For that, you have a great example here: [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage) based on `oncontextmenu` javascript event: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncontextmenu.asp

As always, there's a library for everything, maybe you'd like to try this one: http://ignitersworld.com/lab/contextMenu.html (I've never used it, first result on Google)

Comment: I know that i can create a js contextmenu, i've done it lots of times, but then i'd have to be able to trigger the "paste" or "Ctrl+v" event programatically, and it can't be done. If it's possible then tell me how because i wouldn't need the context menu in the first place :D