# how to edit the style of the default right click menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I find that the default right click menu is very useful. However, I don't like how it looks. Is there any way that I can edit only the style of the default right click menu with HTML, CSS, JS? (in a website)

Thanks!

EDIT: Some have said that my question was not clear, so, let me clear up any doubts.
I want the default right click menu to appear, and not make a custom one. I just want to change the look of the right click menu.

Comment: do you want to change the style of the menu button from the `front`, in real time? the question is not quite clear.

Comment: @Ben.S I dont want a completely custom right click menu, I just want the default one to appear but with a different look (CSS).

Comment: You cant "edit" the default right click menu, but you can definitely build a totally custom one as said by @Ben.S

Comment: If not a dupe of [/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage) then the answer is no. You cannot style built-in elements like alert and context menus