# Youtube's custom right click menu options

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I was using youtube and realized that if you right-click a video twice (once to bring up youtube's right-click menu, and a second time while its menu is already up) it opens the browser's right-click menu with additional options. Specifically, on Firefox, it has the added options: Play, Mute, Speed (expands to speed options), Loop, Full Screen, and Show Controls. This also works on Edge yielding the new options: Loop and Show Controls. My question is how was this done? Also, if I wanted to add right click menu options to a `div` what would I have to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: If you want to create a custom contextmenu, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the browser default contextmenu when you right click any video.

To create a custom contextmenu, check this out: [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)