# how to display contextmenu in select option javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the dropdown option value when I right-click on any option. At the moment when I right-click on the option, it simply selects the option and closes the dropdown instead of calling the **getCountryName** method and displaying it in the alert.

Could you please help me to achieve this?

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddlCountry">
        <option val="Sweden" oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this); return false;">Sweden</option>
        <option val="Denmark" oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this); return false;">Denmark</option>
        <option val="Germany" oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this); return false;">Germany</option>
        <option val="France" oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this); return false;">France</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCountryName(t) {
        alert(t.value);       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea. This goes against any common expectation the average user will have, how select fields work.

Comment: I think this is not possible, at least not across browsers. In Firefox a right-click on the opened options list of a select element [doesn't trigger any events](https://jsfiddle.net/vq2n59hy/), not even an event in capture mode attached to a wrapper of the select element, or the to the select element itself.

Comment: did you look this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom dropdown menu to solve your problem am using bootstrap to demonstrate

```js
function getCountryName(t) {
  alert(t.getAttribute("data-value"));       
}
//Prevent default behaviour
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => e.preventDefault());
```

```css
li:hover {
    background: rgb(189, 189, 247);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Country
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this)" data-value="Sweden">Sweden</li>
      <li oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this)" data-value="Denmark">Denmark</li>
      <li oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this)" data-value="Germany">Germany</li>
      <li oncontextmenu="getCountryName(this)" data-value="France">France</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It was my downvote. Now upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the HTML select and option elements.
You could create a custom dropdown, e.g. as demonstrated on [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) and then add the oncontextmenu events there.