# right click event on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run the following code on IE but not able to get the '`event.which`' as '3' / event that alert itself is not coming, when I right click.

```
 $(document).bind('click', function(event) { 

 alert("event.which = "+event.which);

});
```

My Base requirement is to bind a click event as above and then if it is a anchor link on which i have clicked then I want to restrict a default options which we usually get on right click like 'Open in new window','BookMark this link' etc.

Thx

Comment: you mean you want to customize default context menu of browser according to your needs ???

Comment: if you want to change the context menu  options of browser then must read this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654568/overriding-the-right-click-context-menu-in-web-browsers-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to disable right click then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //disable the right mouse click menu
     $(document)[0].oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}
});
```

Did you mean something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Below code should work: (tested in IE 7)

```
$(document).mousedown(function () {
    if (event.button == 2 && event.srcElement.id == 'your element id') {
        alert('right click not allowed');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to block context menu on anchor element then
This will prevent the context menu from appearing on a particular element

```
$('a').observe("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.stop();
});
```

So, if you wish to stop all anchor tags from showing a context menu

```
$('a').each(function(anch){
    $(anch).observe("contextmenu", function(e){
        e.stop();
    });
})
```

i think you want something different then this but 
see if this is your need