# jquery act on right click when user tries to open a new window

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, refactoring

I have a Bootstrap modal with a simple button link in it. Right now I am working with the following:

```
jQuery('#jobPostWarning').find('a').mousedown(function(e) {
     if(e.which === 3) {
        jQuery(this).find('a').trigger("click");
     }
});
```

The goal here is the make the right click work the same as the left when a user tries to open a new window on the modal link_to button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this:

[How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)

Overriding a browsers right click menu isn't very reliable though.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654568/overriding-the-right-click-context-menu-in-web-browsers-pros-and-cons) for more details.